# Arraylist is coming as string in while sending in webservice

Tags: java, json, web-services, arraylist, jersey

```
 JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
  try {


        testVoList.add(new TestVO(1L, "HAI1"));
        testVoList.add(new TestVO(2L, "HAI2"));

        myObject.put("name", testVoList);          


    } catch (JSONException ex) {
     }
    String s = URLEncoder.encode(myObject.toString(), "UTF-8");     
    URL url = new URL("urlName/"+s);
```

**CODE IN WEBSERVICE TO RECIEVE DATA:**

```
@POST
@Path("/urlName/{test}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String saveSurveyresponseData(@PathParam("test") JSONObject responseData)
{
     JSONArray.fromObject(responseData.getString("name")).get(0);           
            return "HAI";
}
```

Here i am getting `test.TestVO@c2ea3f`(Hashcode) for

```
JSONArray.fromObject(responseData.getString("name")).get(0);
```

How can I access my list of objects values in my webservice.

Can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: You tag your question with jersy: did you mean jersey?

Comment: @ruffp jersy web services

Comment: I do not find any reference to jersy web-services, can you share a link?

Comment: @ruffp http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: That is Jersey then...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following statement:

```
 JSONArray.fromObject(responseData.getString("name")).get(0);
```

is returning the list. So simply assign it to a list reference as mentioned here:

```
List<TestVO> listOfTestVO = JSONArray.fromObject(responseData.getString("name")).get(0);
```

Now simply get the elements as:

```
listOfTestVO.get(1);
```

Comment: i need to create testVo in serverside also?

Comment: TestVO is not created in serverside

Comment: @PSR TestVO is actually your DTO, which should be present on both client and server side.